# Simpler to way to do == x or y, x etc

Tags: r

I'm trying to recode a dataframe and assign everything above the value of 11 to a finite limit to just one number.

```
constant_newspapers[constant_newspapers$f_paperm2 == c(11:24)]             <- 11
```

I didn't think the vector notation would work but I thought it worth a try! As an aside, is there a way to do this within in the tidyverse universe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pmin()` (parallel minimum) function will do this efficiently. `pmin()` is a base-R function, but will work perfectly well in conjunction with tidyverse machinery.

```
constant_newspapers$f_paperm2 <- pmin(11,constant_newspapers$f_paperm2)
```

or in tidyverse maybe:

```
constant_newspapers %<>%
       mutate_at("f_paperm2", ~ pmin(., 11))
```

`pmin()` works because your criterion is a simple numerical bound.  If you wanted (e.g.) to change values 14, 17, and 20 to 0 (and your data set contained some of the values between, you'd need `%in%` as previously suggested in a comment:

```
constant_newspapers %<>%
   mutate_at("f_paperm2", 
        ~ ifelse(. %in% target_values,
               replace_value, .))
```

or

```
constant_newspapers %<>%
   mutate_at("f_paperm2", 
        ~ replace(.,which(. %in% target_values,
                  replace_value)))
```

Comment: pmin() worked brilliantly thank-you but I have to ask, is the %<>% you use in the tidyverse syntax a typo or a different pipe operator ? Either way, thanks ever so much !

Comment: See `?"%<>%"`: "Pipe an object forward into a function or call expression and update the ‘lhs’ object with the resulting value."